# Fourier transform of positive momentum states only?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, eigenvalue

Suppose I have the momentum-space eigenstates of a system $\psi_n(p)$. I write the time-evolved momentum states as $\Psi(p,t) = \sum c_n\psi_n(p)e^{-i E_n t}$ where $E_n$ are the corresponding energy eigenvalues.

**My Goal:** To construct a position-space solution (not general) of the Schrödinger equation, formed entirely of positive momentum states.

**Question:**
My naïve guess was to take the Fourier transform over only positive momenta, i.e.
$$\Phi(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Theta(p) \Psi(p,t)e^{i p x} dp$$
where $\Theta(p)$ is The Heaviside Step function.

But I could not show (probably isn't true) that such a function would indeed be a solution to the Time-Dependent SE (which is satisfied by $\Psi(p,t)$ in momentum-space).

Is there any method/idea to achieve the aforementioned 'goal'?

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried?

Comment: Your notation doesn't make sense.  $n$ is a dummy index which is summed over on the RHS of your expression, but it also appears on the left.

Comment: @J.MurrayI have edited the notation to make more sense - the previous one was a typo.

Comment: @NiharKarve I added what my naive guess was, but there isn't really much to show from my side. I am asking for references for constructing the $\Phi(x,t)$ state with only positive momenta. My approach itself might be wrong on the long run.

Comment: approach is fine, you can also use the Fourier convolution theorem to convert any $\Phi(x,t)$ into a positive momentum only state.  It will still solve TDSE, in the sense you can always calculate time evolution of a state.